# Given an integer $n$ find the smallest index $k$ such that $\text{fib}(k) \ge n$ in logarithmic time?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algorithms, fibonacci-numbers, recursive-algorithms

> Given an integer $n$ find the smallest index $k$ such that $\text{fib}(k) \ge n$ in logarithmic time?

I've already programmed several algorithms to compute the $i$'th Fibonacci number $\text{fib}(i)$ in logarithmic time, i.e. by using a clever recurrence relation and matrix exponentation.

Computing $\text{fib}(k) \ge n$ in linear time is easy by using to accumulators and then incrementially proceed.

However, the logarithmic procedures operate top-down wrt. $i$ with base case $i=0$.

Any ideas?

Comment: In logarithmic time as a function of what ? Any algorithm will be at least linear in the number of digits of $n$, and I can't imagine a solution faster than $\log n\log\log n$. How large is $n$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A(n)$ be the algorithm that return $(k,fib(k),fib(k-1)$ where $k$ is the smallest $k$ such that $fib(k)\geq n$

We defined $A(n)$ as follow:
$A(n)=(1,1,0)$ if $n=1$

otherwise let $(k,f_1,f_2)=A(n/2)$; $n\leq f_1$ return $(k,f_1,f_2)$ otherwise if $n\leq f_1+f_2$ return $(k+1,f_1+f_2,f_1)$ otherwise return $(k+2,2*f_1+f_2,f_1+f_2)$

Comment: How do I compute $A(n/2)$?

Comment: How do you argue that it is logarithmic?

Comment: Isn't this logarithmic squared ($\log(n)^2$), i.e. linear?

Comment: @Shuzheng Edited. logarithmic number of call. and constant number of operation per call.

Comment: What exactly are the components of the vector? If the vector is $(k, fib_k, fib_{k-1})$ then this vector is not updated correctly?

Comment: Ahh, I see... Excellent answer! You definitely deserve +1 :-)

Comment: Hmm, last question. Why wouldn't the version using two accumulators, i.e. computing the Fibonacci number in a for loop not be linear? Each time we compute a new Fibonacci number it almost doubles, so this must also be logarithmic?

Comment: I disagree with the analysis. "constant number of operation per call" implies that $n$ and $F_k$ are bounded (like fitting in a register). If $n$ is bounded, this is an $O(1)$ problem and the best approach is to tabulate all representable Fibonacci numbers and solve by dichotomic search, never exceeding $94$ comparisons on a $64$ bits machine. If $n$ is unbounded, then the complexity must exceed $O(\log n)$, as you can't do with a constant number of comparisons.

Comment: @Shuzheng Yes it is also logarithmic

Comment: @YvesDaoust I assumed comparison and addition of integer to be $O(1)$ isn't that standard in complexity analysis?

Comment: @wece: technically speaking, if you adopt $O(1)$ for $n$, then the whole problem is $O(1)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How so?

Comment: @wece It is not in fact standard for comparison and addition of integers to be considered O(1) when those integers can be of arbitrary sizes; it's not uncommon either (e.g. for discussion sort routines, where a surprising amount of sloppiness can slip in), but more common for problems involving arithmetic is to count the number of bit operations.

Comment: Isn't this literally just OP's algorithm (linear w/ accumulators) expressed in slightly more formal terms?

Comment: @wece - what would a linear algorithm be then? By simply iteration one obtains logarithmic, so how could it be slow?

Comment: @Shuzheng My first attempt was slow :D if you re-compute $fib(k)$ each time it is slow ...

Comment: @wece - How do your algorithm tolerate odd numbers?

Comment: @Shuzheng If the numbers fit in one register as is hypothetized by wece, it is a nonsense to recompute them every time. It is much faster and possibly even more compact to tabulate.

Comment: @Shuzheng you can take either floor, ceiling, or rounding for $n/2$ all the three should work.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I still don't see how the whole problem is $O(1)$ is addition and comparison are $O(1)$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ok, thank you for your comment. Is there an hope to have a logarithmic algorithm if you count the number of bit operation? This would mean that you could solve the problem in constant time with basic operation in $O(1)$ no?

Comment: @wece: any problem with bounded size is $O(1)$.

Answer (score 4):

This isn’t an algorithm; it’s a closed form for the smallest $k$ such that $F_k\le n<F_{k+1}$, from which it’s not hard to get what you want.

It’s easy to prove from [Binet’s exact formula for $F_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) that $F_n$ is the integer nearest $\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}$, where $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$, and hence that

$$F_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;.$$

An immediate consequence of this is that if $F>1$ is a Fibonacci number, its index in the Fibonacci sequence is

$$\left\lfloor\log_\varphi\left(F\sqrt5+\frac12\right)\right\rfloor\;.$$

It follows that if $F_k\le n<F_{k+1}$, then

$$k=\left\lfloor\log_\varphi\left(n\sqrt5+\frac12\right)\right\rfloor\;,$$

and only a little minor manipulation is required to get what you want.

Comment: I expect one needs high-precision approximation of $\varphi$ and $\sqrt 5$ for this formula to work for high values of $n$.

Comment: @lhf: only when $n$ is close to a Fibonacci number. The method will just hesitate between $k$ and $k+1$, even using single-precision floating-point and $n$ with a million digits.

Comment: Great answer! I really think this is a great way to compute Fibonacci, however, the other answer is more in line what I anticipated. +1

Comment: @lhf: Yes, so do I, though perhaps not so high-precision as one might guess: it gives the right results for $F_{40}=102,334,155$ and $F_{40}-1$ on the [Excalibur](http://www.freeware-guide.com/OldGoodFreeware/Excalibur.html) Windows calculator, which uses an $8$ byte IEEE floating point representation.

Comment: @Shuzheng: Yes, I suspected that you were looking for something more algorithmic; I just thought that it would be nice to point out for future readers that a closed form is also possible.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott On an completely unrelated note, I think you might have just changed my calculator selection.  It's not usual to find an RPN calculator app. :)

Comment: @apnorton: I love that calculator app! I find RPN a *much* easier way to think when I’m using a calculator. My first calculator (other than a slide rule!) was the [HP-55](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-55), which came out the year I started teaching. If you ever want one for an Android device, I can recommend [EBTCalc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ericbt.rpncalcpaid).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Awesome! I'll install that Android app (it's a perpetual bother to me to use algebraic notation on my phone).  I've been using an HP-35S for a scientific calculator for a few years now, and I've had an HP-50G as my graphing calculator since some time in high school. :)

Comment: Just to be sure, after I compute k, I compute fib(k) and then see if fib(k) = n, where n is the value to compute k for. If this is not the case, I return k+1?

Comment: @Shuzheng: You can do that, or you can compute the $k$ for $n-1$: if they’re the same, return $k+1$, and otherwise return the original $k$.

Answer (score 1):

For a finite size solution, perform a dichotomic search in the table below (blue up to 32 bits, 64 otherwise). This never takes more than $7$ comparisons.

$$\color{blue}{0:0\\
1:1\\
2:1\\
3:2\\
4:3\\
5:5\\
6:8\\
7:13\\
8:21\\
9:34\\
10:55\\
11:89\\
12:144\\
13:233\\
14:377\\
15:610\\
16:987\\
17:1597\\
18:2584\\
19:4181\\
20:6765\\
21:10946\\
22:17711\\
23:28657\\
24:46368\\
25:75025\\
26:121393\\
27:196418\\
28:317811\\
29:514229\\
30:832040\\
31:1346269\\
32:2178309\\
33:3524578\\
34:5702887\\
35:9227465\\
36:14930352\\
37:24157817\\
38:39088169\\
39:63245986\\
40:102334155\\
41:165580141\\
42:267914296\\
43:433494437\\
44:701408733\\
45:1134903170\\
46:1836311903\\
47:2971215073}\\
48:4807526976\\
49:7778742049\\
50:12586269025\\
51:20365011074\\
52:32951280099\\
53:53316291173\\
54:86267571272\\
55:139583862445\\
56:225851433717\\
57:365435296162\\
58:591286729879\\
59:956722026041\\
60:1548008755920\\
61:2504730781961\\
62:4052739537881\\
63:6557470319842\\
64:10610209857723\\
65:17167680177565\\
66:27777890035288\\
67:44945570212853\\
68:72723460248141\\
69:117669030460994\\
70:190392490709135\\
71:308061521170129\\
72:498454011879264\\
73:806515533049393\\
74:1304969544928657\\
75:2111485077978050\\
76:3416454622906707\\
77:5527939700884757\\
78:8944394323791464\\
79:14472334024676221\\
80:23416728348467685\\
81:37889062373143906\\
82:61305790721611591\\
83:99194853094755497\\
84:160500643816367088\\
85:259695496911122585\\
86:420196140727489673\\
87:679891637638612258\\
88:1100087778366101931\\
89:1779979416004714189\\
90:2880067194370816120\\
91:4660046610375530309\\
92:7540113804746346429\\
93:12200160415121876738\\
$$